# formula for positive root of $ x + x^2 + x^3 + ((a-b)/a) $ where the constant is negative

Tags: polynomials

I am interested in this for practical purposes. Is there a simple formula for this? I found the general formula, which gives three potential solutions, but I am wondering if there is a simpler expression for the positive solution of this specific type of polynomial.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? A polynomial with all positive coefficients should not have any positive real roots.

Comment: So the equation is $x^3+x^2+x+(a-b)/a=0$ and the constant coefficient is negative. You should edit the title. Also, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017770/what-is-the-condition-for-the-first-root-of-a-cubic-function-to-be-positive).

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you are looking for the solution of
$$x^3+x^2+x-k=0 \qquad \text{where} \qquad k=-\frac{a-b}a \,\,\, >0$$

Using the methods described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), you have $\Delta=-(27 k^2+14 k+3) <0$; so, only one real root.

Using the [hyperbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root), you then have
$$\color{blue}{x=\frac{1}{3} \left(1-2 \sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{27
   k+7}{4 \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)}$$